# How to log exceptions from django management commands to file without hacking manage,py?

Tags: django

Consider the following manage.py command:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        raise Exception('Test exception')
```

Is there a way to make django log that exception to a specific file automatically without wrapping handle() function in a big try-catch or without hacking the manage.py itself, which basically mean I do the logging myself.

I mean something like configuring admin mail handler for views, but log to file instead of an email and management command instead of a view. Then raise exceptions from any place inside a management command and be sure they will be logged.